# Mikrotik - 5GHz AC - only 110Mbps

Tags: wifi, mikrotik

I just bought [Mikrotik hAP AC^2](https://mikrotik.com/product/hap_ac2) and I configured it's WiFi to be controlled by CAPsMAN. The problem I have is that when I connect to it with my laptop (MacBook Pro 2016 Touchbar) I cannot achieve more than 110Mbps. On cable I can achieve 560Mbps.

Provision:

```
0   radio-mac=00:00:00:00:00:00 hw-supported-modes=gn identity-regexp="" common-name-regexp="" ip-address-ranges="" action=create-dynamic-enabled master-configuration=cfg1 slave-configurations="" name-format=prefix-identity 
     name-prefix="2GHz" 

1   radio-mac=00:00:00:00:00:00 hw-supported-modes=ac identity-regexp="" common-name-regexp="" ip-address-ranges="" action=create-dynamic-enabled master-configuration=cfg2 slave-configurations="" name-format=prefix-identity 
     name-prefix="5GHz"
```

Configuration:

```
 0 name="cfg1" ssid="SSID" security=security1 datapath=datapath1 channel=channel1 

 1 name="cfg2" ssid="SSID" security=security1 datapath=datapath1 channel=channel2
```

Channel:

```
0 name="channel1" control-channel-width=20mhz band=2ghz-onlyn 

1 name="channel2" control-channel-width=20mhz band=5ghz-onlyac
```

Datapath:

```
 0 name="datapath1" bridge=bridge
```

Security:

```
 0 name="security1" authentication-types=wpa2-psk encryption=aes-ccm passphrase="*****"
```

In registration table I see 866Mbps and it's using both antennas, but when I test I get only 120Mbps. The device is 1M away from router, ALMOST clear. (there is a wired PC between them)
[image: Registration table]

This is interface: [image]

This is signal strength from device:

```
 PHY Mode:  802.11ac
  Channel:  36
  Country Code: BG
  Network Type: Infrastructure
  Security: WPA2 Personal
  Signal / Noise:   -50 dBm / -93 dBm
  Transmit Rate:    527
  MCS Index:    6
```

After detaching 5GHz interface from CAPsMAN the speed raised to 400Mbps.
After attaching again I saw I hit the CPU limit.

```
cpu-used: 26%
cpu-used-per-cpu: 0%,1%,4%,100%
```

[image]

This one is when I'm detached from CAPsMAN.
[image]

So I'm hitting CPU limit - but why?

Comment: Are you sure you are not comparing bits ve Bytes. Like mbps is 1/8 MBps.

Comment: Yup, I'm sure. :)

Comment: That transmit rate you see on your mac is the transmit rate at which your mac is operating, in this case 527 Mbps. It will jump around, depending on interference, noise, etc. If the problem is with hitting CPU limits while trying to transfer data, a better way to pose the question would be why does the device has such high CPU usage while using CAPsMAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned on `Local forwarding` in `Datapath` and bridged wlan interfaces and now I achieve 400 mbps with CAPsMAN controlled APs.